# MySQL add date fields and compare to today on where clause

Tags: mysql

I am struggling with this one and getting a syntax error.

Trying to get campaigns that are still ongoing, ie, where start_date + duration_days is >= than today.

I've also tried with DATE_ADD with the same result.

start_date is a DATE field, while duration_days is INT.

```
SELECT id,start_date,duration_days
                FROM `myTable`
                WHERE start_date + INTERVAL duration_days DAYS >= CURDATE()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the interval to DAY not DAYS, that's what is throwing the error.

```
SELECT id,start_date,duration_days
            FROM `myTable`
            WHERE start_date + INTERVAL duration_days DAY >= CURDATE()
```

Comment: Thanks @Niagaradad. I thought it was something silly, as usual.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the DATE_ADD and DATE_SUB functions to manipulate dates rather than the arithmetic operators:

```
SELECT id,start_date,duration_days
FROM `myTable`
WHERE DATE_ADD(start_date, INTERVAL duration_days DAYS) >= CURDATE()
```

Comment: Actually the arithmetic operators are allowed, the problem is it should be DAY and not DAYS.

Comment: Thanks, my MySQL knowledge is obviously a bit out of date.  I didn't know that